# Unable to load data from array into a jquery mobile dialog page via angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Im practicing angularJS and jquery mobile. Im loading a local stored `json` file (used an array here) to my app and present some basic info in a list view. I want to present more detailed info in a `dialog` page\box once the user clicks on something in the JQM `listview`. Right now im able to present the basic info in the `listview` but pretty clueless regarding the next step. Please advise.
I was thinking that the one controller that i have can manage two pages, but this is obviously wrong.

JS code:

```
var myCuponApp = angular.module("cupon", []);

myCuponApp.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.itemSet = [{"id": 1, "cuponName": "Nikola Tesla", "age": "45"}];
});
```

html code:

```
<head ng-app="cupon">
    <div data-role="page" id="scientists" ng-controller="controller">
        <div data-role="header"><h3>great scientists</h3></div>

        <div data-role="content">
                <div>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in itemSet" data-role="button"><a href="#sc" data-rel="dialog">{{item.cuponName}}</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
         </div>
     </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="sc" ng-controller="controller">
        <div>{{item.cuponName}}</div>
    </div>
</head>
```

Comment: You have ng-app declared twice...you only need that declared once up on your <html/> element.

Comment: thanks, fixed that. can you shed some light regarding the other questions?